# $mail ->send() not functioning

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i have php code to send a mail depending on the message and body . but the mail isnt getting sent and no error

can anyone tell me whats the problem here

```
if ($userid == null) {
  $smtpusername     = "smtp". rand(1,20)."@nithin.com";
  $mail->IsSMTP();                   // telling the class to use SMTP
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = SMTPAUTH;      // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Host       = SMTPHOST;      // sets the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = SMTPPORT ;     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->SMTPSecure = SMTPSECURE;    // Use ssl or tls to secure smtp calls
  $mail->Username   = $smtpusername; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = SMTPPASSWORD;  // SMTP account password
  $mail->SetFrom('nithin@nithin.com','abc');
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
}
else {
  //TODO: Fetch preferences, refer Taskera 1.0 version
}
$toarray          = explode(',', $to);
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($htmlbody);
for($toiter = 0; $toiter < count($toarray); $toiter++)
  $mail->AddAddress($toarray[$toiter], "");
$result = ($mail->Send());
if (!$result) {
   $this->debug('MAILERROR', __FUNCTION__, 'Message sending failed. Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
  return FAILURE;
}
```

error

```
[Tue Jul 07 09:55:24 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.232] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class PHPMailer could not be converted to string in /var/www/inc/base.inc on line 68, referer: https://www.nithin.com/
```

line 68

```
protected
  function debug($function, $variable) {
    if (is_array($variable))
      $output = sprintf(" DEBUG: == %s()     [%s]", $function, print_r($variable, true));
    else
      $output = sprintf(" DEBUG: == %s()     (%s)", $function, $variable);
    error_log($output);
  }
```

Comment: PHPMailer is much more reliable and better to use instead of the mail function from PHP

Comment: What's the output of the SMTPDebug ?

Comment: what is in line 68??

Comment: protected
  function debug($function, $variable) {
    if (is_array($variable))
      $output = sprintf(" DEBUG: == %s()     [%s]", $function, print_r($variable, true));
    else
      $output = sprintf(" DEBUG: == %s()     (%s)", $function, $variable);
    error_log($output);
  }

Comment: When are you calling this function?

Comment: its just a debug function for overall site.

Comment: This is simply a bug in your debug output function - you're trying to print an object as a string. Why don't you use PHPMailer's built-in debugging functions? If you set `SMTPDebug = 2` you will see what the server is saying to you.